# Is it bad to use roles/storage.legacyBucketWriter to read/write in a bucket?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-iam

I find myself using a lot **roles/storage.legacyBucketWriter** which has the following permissions:

- *storage.buckets.get*
- *storage.objects.create*
- *storage.objects.delete*
- *storage.objects.list*

May be it's okay but it feels odd to me to be using a role with *legacy* in its name ...

I don't want to create a custom role either because it seems overkill since there is this role fitting the need.

And yes there is a role **roles/storage.objectAdmin** but it lacks the *storage.buckets.get* permission.

What do you think ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remember legacy roles are related to primitive roles on GCP, It is 'Legacy' because it exactly matches the pre-IAM permissions granted via the legacy role on an Object. It all depends on your use case, the best recommended practice is to follow the principle of least privilege.

Keep in mind as is mentioned at the official [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/iam#acls):

> Legacy Bucket IAM roles work in tandem with bucket ACLs: when you add
> or remove a Legacy Bucket role, the ACLs associated with the bucket
> reflect your changes.

Also, consider the scope of the read/write legacy roles as is described on this [table](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/iam-roles#legacy-roles).

Finally take a look at the [section](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/best-practices#security) of Security, ACLs, and access control for follow the best practices recommended for Cloud Storage service.

Comment: Ok, I'd missed the part that legacy bucket IAM where working in tandem with bucket ACLs. But on the other hand I would like that there is non legacy role with the same permissions as roles/storage.legacyBucketWriter and not to have to create a custom one since I've the feeling that it's a common usecase.

Comment: you can fill a feature request for that https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers

Answer (score 3):

Consider using the **Storage Admin** Role (`roles/storage.admin`) instead of a legacy role. This role grants both `storage.buckets.*` and `storage.objects.*` permissions, making it a suitable match for your requirements.

According to the Storage Admin Role [description](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/iam-roles#standard-roles), this role

> grants full control over buckets and objects. When applied to an individual bucket, control is limited to that specific bucket and its associated objects.

This role is particularly useful when utilizing the `gsutil rsync` command targeting a bucket.